# What materials are used for human spacecraft pressure vessels and why?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, spacecraft, materials, orion-spacecraft, human-rating

I'm looking for what specific aluminum alloys are used for human-rated spacecraft pressure vessels (habitable module) and why.

I've been able to find the material for Orion is Al-2219 but nothing for Apollo, Dragon, Starliner, Gaganyaan, Soyuz, Orel PTK (Soyuz successor).

High-strength aluminum such as 2XXX or 7XXX series requires expensive friction stir welding so I'm curious if other materials have been successfully used and what factors (other than strength-to-weight and stiffness) drive the need for these alloys. For example, stress-corrosion cracking (SCC) and strength at elevated temperature must have been considered. Has anyone seen a paper that discusses this as it relates to human spacecraft and what specific factors drove a certain material? Yes, I've searched NTRS.
Thanks!

**NASA Orion MPCV:**
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20160003616
[image]

Comment: the BBC link following "Boeing CST-100 Starliner" doesn't appear to have anything to do with Starliner. I've upvoted because I think it's an interesting question, but not sure what to do with that link

Comment: From https://www.lightmetalage.com/news/industry-news/aerospace/50th-anniversary-of-apollo-11-mission-to-the-moon-made-possible-with-aluminum/ - "Alcoa was a major supplier to the program, providing over a million pounds of specialty aluminum alloy 2219 for the Saturn V rocket series alone." Given that friction stir welding, although patented (in Russia) in 1967, was not a common process until the 1990s, and thus is highly unlikely to have been used on Apollo.

Comment: The shuttle crew cabins were of conventional aircraft aluminum construction.

Comment: @ErinAnne, you're correct. I think I added the wrong link but now can't find anything on Starliner materials at all.